# How to customize the emails sent by Laravel Breeze?

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, laravel-breeze

I wanted to customize the emails sent by Breeze from the default styles. Looks like the installation of Breeze does not publish the files for that but I found online that using `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications` will publish the email files, and it did, although looks like it did not publish all the necessary files (it only published one file)

It only published `/vendor/notifications/email.blade.php`, with the following code, but looks like other things are missing like the components themselves such as the `x-mail::button`?

```
<x-mail::message>
{{-- Greeting --}}
@if (! empty($greeting))
# {{ $greeting }}
@else
@if ($level === 'error')
# @lang('Whoops!')
@else
# @lang('Hello!')
@endif
@endif

{{-- Intro Lines --}}
@foreach ($introLines as $line)
{{ $line }}

@endforeach

{{-- Action Button --}}
@isset($actionText)
<?php
    $color = match ($level) {
        'success', 'error' => $level,
        default => 'primary',
    };
?>
<x-mail::button :url="$actionUrl" :color="$color">
{{ $actionText }}
</x-mail::button>
@endisset

{{-- Outro Lines --}}
@foreach ($outroLines as $line)
{{ $line }}

@endforeach

{{-- Salutation --}}
@if (! empty($salutation))
{{ $salutation }}
@else
@lang('Regards'),<br>
{{ config('app.name') }}
@endif

{{-- Subcopy --}}
@isset($actionText)
<x-slot:subcopy>
@lang(
    "If you're having trouble clicking the \":actionText\" button, copy and paste the URL below\n".
    'into your web browser:',
    [
        'actionText' => $actionText,
    ]
) <span class="break-all">[{{ $displayableActionUrl }}]({{ $actionUrl }})</span>
</x-slot:subcopy>
@endisset
</x-mail::message>
```

How can I customize that? The buttons for example? Because looks like this template is working for all the types of emails (welcome, verification, password-reset), so I can't just replace the contents with my code but I somehow need only to change the styles

Comment: php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail
this one should publish /views/vendor/mail html/text and components, seems you published notifications without reading mail section in the docs, anyway i had trouble with these so i'm not quiet sure

Comment: @Elboyler haha you are correct, after I published the mail it published the correct files, thank you